# i accidently unselected all privilege's for root in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, privileges

so i was messing around and i accidently unselected all the privileges' for my root user for phpmyadmin
[image]

how can i go about fixing this
i tried doing

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv = 'Y', Super_priv = 'Y' WHERE User = 'root'
```

but it gives an error saying

```
#1142 - UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```